# Import -csv to change givenname through power shell

Tags: powershell, csv, import

Hello I am new to powershell and have successfully imported over 400 users using a csv file. I had a typo in my CSV file that caused the given name to be firstname+lastname instead of just the user's first name. I am trying to change JUST the first name of these users that are in the "TestOU" OU. I am looking at the easiest way to do this with only changing the givenname of each user as everything else is correct.

Server 2012 R2
The users are located in cn=domain users,ou=testou,dc=school,dc=local

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TestOU,DC=school,DC=local" | ForEach-Object { Set-ADUser -GiveName ... }`. What you pass to `-GivenName` depends on what's in your CSV.

Comment: Thanks Alexander I will try this out.  I have my csv file setup like this. Container/OU,Givenname,Surname,Name,DisplayName,Logon Name,Password,sAMAccountName,DomainName
"cn=Domain Users,ou=testou,dc=school,dc=local"

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much what Alexander said to get only the users in that OU...

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase ",OU=TestOU,DC=school,DC=local"
```

Then you can calculate what the GivenName should have been by removing the surname from it, and trimming for extra trailing spaces.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase ",OU=TestOU,DC=school,DC=local" | ForEach-Object { 
    $Given = $_.GivenName -replace $_.SurName
    $_ | Set-ADUser -GiveName $Given.Trim()
}
```

**Edit:** However unlikely it seems to me, I should warn you that if a user has identical first and last names, and the GivenName field only has their first name it will leave the field blank. So if their name is "Andrew Andrew", where 'Andrew' is both their first and last name, and the GivenName field is currently set to 'Andrew' it will erase it. I suppose you could add some logic in there to avoid that...

```
If(!([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Given.Trim()))){
    $_ | Set-ADUser -GivenName $Given.Trim()
}
```

That should do it I suppose, to avoid blank GivenName fields.

**Edit2:** You know, if you still have your CSV you could do this easier. Fix your GivenName column. Remove all columns except that one and the SAMAccountName column. Then you should be able to just do:

```
Import-CSV 'C:\Path\To\File.csv' | ForEach{ Set-ADUser $_.samaccountname -GivenName $_.GivenName }
```

Comment: OK i ran your command and it finishes, no errors and returns me to a prompt but I then check the names of users in the testou OU and has not changed their first names.

Comment: Ok, try my update. It's simpler, assuming you still have your CSV. And if you don't have your CSV... Why would you get rid of something like that while this whole thing is still pending?

Comment: No luck man, tried both ways, with my old csv file, fixed my Givenname field to have everyone's first names only and used your code.  If I use the old users.csv file I get this error:  Set-ADUser: cannot find an object with identity "first.lastname" under: 'dc=school,dc=local'. at line:1 char:66.   If I use just the Givenname tab in my csv I get this error: Set-ADUser: cannot validate arguement on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null.

Comment: Are your user names formatted `firstname.lastname`? For example, a user would login with something like `school\jim.anderson`? Or would it be something more like `school\jande` for their login?

Comment: Yes the usernames they use to login are: domain\firstname.lastname. Display Name is first name lastname ( there is a space in between the names).